# How to access to Doctrine Document Manager from Doctrine Entity Repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have a doctrine entity User and a document Address (stored in mongoDB). I want to set an one to many relation between them by userId property. (the user has many addresses)

My User Entity:

```
namespace BlaBla\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $firstName;
```

... and so on

My Address document:

```
namespace BlaBla\UserBundle\Document;
/**
 * BlaBla\UserBundle\Document\Address
 */
class Address
{
/**
 * @var MongoId $id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string $firstName
 */
protected $firstName;

/**
 * @var string $lastName
 */
protected $lastName;

/**
 * @var int $userId
 */
protected $userId;
```

... and so on

My goal is to create the getUser() method for the Address object and the getAddresses() method for the User object.

I've decided to place the method getAddresses() to the doctrine UserRepository class and to inject there the necessary document manager to be able to access to the Address Document. I've overriden the constructor of the userRepository and passed to it the necessary document manager object.

Please, look to the UserRepository class:

```
<?php

namespace BlaBla\UserBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager
 */
private $_dm;

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $dm
 */
public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, $dm) {

    $metaData = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata('BlaBla\UserBundle\Entity\User');
    parent::__construct($em, $metaData);
    $this->_dm = $dm;
}

/**
 * @param $user_id integer
 * @return \BlaBla\UserBundle\Document\Address
 */
public function getAddress($user_id) {
    $address = $this->_dm->getRepository('BlaBlaUserBundle:Address');
    $rt = $address->findByUserId($user_id);
    return $rt;
}

public function getAllUsers()
{
    return $this->findAll();
}
}
```

After this I can access to the repository from my controller via:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
    $t = new \BlaBla\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository($em, $dm);
    var_dump($t->getAddress($id));
    var_dump($t->getAllUsers());
```

Both methods work just fine, but now I can't access to the repository using shortcuts like:

```
 $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BlaBlaUserBundle:User');
```

I thought about making the Repository as service with something like this:

```
user.repository:
   class: BlaBla\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository
   arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @doctrine.odm.mongo_db.document_manager]
```

in my services.yml file, but this only lets me to access the repository with:

```
$this->get('user.repository');
```

the default shortcuts doesn't work still.

Please help to find a correct solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you specified the UserRepository? In your User.php with annotation ? Maybe that is the only thing what is missing.
But if you want to use entity and document repository, I advise you to use Doctrine extensions, specifically [Reference](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/references.md).